# Read S3 CSV file and insert into RDS mysql using AWS Glue

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, amazon-rds

I have a CSV file in S3 bucket which gets updated/refreshed with new data generated from ML model every week. I have created an ETL pipeline in AWS glue to read data(CSV file) from S3 bucket and load it into RDS(mysql server). I have connected my RDS via SSMS. I was able to load data successfully into RDS and validate currect row counts with `50000`. When I run the job again, the whole table; ie same file contents in CSV file gets appended. Here is the sample code:

```
datasink5 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = resolvechoice4, database = "<dbname>", table_name = "<table schema name>", transformation_ctx = "datasink5")
```

Next week when I run my model there will be `1000` new rows in that CSV file. So when I run my ETL job in Glue, it should append 1000 new row values with previously loaded `5000` rows. Total row counts should reflect as `6000`.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this? Is there anyway we can truncate or drop  table before inserting all new data? In that way we could avoid duplication.

Note: I will have to run "Crawler" to read data from S3 bucket every week to get new data with existing row values.

sample code generate using AWS glue.

```
## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to only insert new data each time the Glue job runs, you should use bookmarks.  The Glue job script will need a corresponding `job.init()` and `job.commit()` for this to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Norman for your reply! I am very new to this ETL process. Above code was a "proposed script generated by AWS glue. whats the best way I could implement that? any reference ?

Comment: @Norman, I have enable bookmarks, can u suggest how to implement that into init() and commit() function?

Comment: It should just be a matter of performing the relevant transformations to the data after the `job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)` then finish with `job.commit()`. Please refer to the following for guidance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html#monitor-continuations-script